# How to include different javascript scripts that have same variable and function names inside

Tags: javascript, include

how can I implement this scenario in javascript?

```
<script defer src="script01.js"></script> 
<script defer src="script02.js"></script>
```

Where script01.js and script02.js have inside duplicate variable names, functions with the same name, etc ..

PS: from script02.js I need to return parameters.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Why not use modules instead? Of course, simply adding `type="module"` won’t be enough. You need to actually _rewrite_ the scripts as modules, export your values, import them elsewhere with _unambiguous_ names, and then use them.

Comment: add `type="module"` see if it work?

Comment: So which variable and function do you want to use?

Comment: These scritps are about 29k lines and I have no intention of correcting them, they come from the same code root but have been changed in the meantime. They both work perfectly individually, but now I have to use them from the same html page.
@Chong Lip Phang - The script02.js will return parameters without the need to use functions and / or variables contained in it.